# Define/use angularjs controller inside internal module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I use Typescript 1.4 with angularjs 1.3.6.

Using VS 2015 RC with webessentials, with no module system (no --module flag)

I have a **working** code like this:

demoModule.ts

```
module Demo.Test {
'use strict';


(() => {
    var app = angular.module('Demo.Test', []);


    // Routes.
    app.config([
        '$stateProvider', $stateProvider => {

            $stateProvider
                .state('demo', {
                url: '/demo',
                templateUrl: '/views/test/demo.html',
                controller: 'demoController as vm'
            });
        }
    ]);
})();
```

demoController.ts

```
module Demo.Test {
    'use strict';
    export class DemoController {
        constructor(/* ... */) { /* ... */}
    }
    angular.module('Demo.Test').controller('demoController', Demo.Test.DemoController);
}
```

But when I move this line:

```
angular.module('Demo.Test').controller('demoController', Demo.Test.DemoController);
```

to the demoModule.ts file(see below) it will compile, but getting JS error when run:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'demoController' is not a function, got undefined

Any idea how can I make it work? I mean like this:

```
module Demo.Test {
'use strict';


(() => {
    var app = angular.module('Demo.Test', []);
    angular.module('Demo.Test').controller('demoController', Demo.Test.DemoController);

    // Routes.
    app.config([
        '$stateProvider', $stateProvider => {

            $stateProvider
                .state('demo', {
                url: '/demo',
                templateUrl: '/views/test/demo.html',
                controller: 'demoController as vm'
            });
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: It's all about files' order, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its got to do with ordering of files. One of the well known errors caused by using `--out` in TypeScript : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md#runtime-errors

Answer (score 2):

If you used the script reference not in the right order, then you are going to get the runtime error.
as: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'demoController' is not a function, got undefined

Add demoController.ts before demoModule.ts in your html file.

```
<script src="demoController.js"></script>
<script src="demoModule.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed ordering, I knew it could be , but seems that I was doing both changes at once (moving the line and reordering).